# Problems saving a file to sdcard in android

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I am trying to get a file to save to my sdcard. Here is the code I have so far. I really appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks
Edit: 
The problem is that the file is not saved. When I exit the program and look at the sdcard no file was saved. I put a toast into the error catchers and it looks like I'm getting an IOException. I don't know how to check the StackTrace log though

```
class bSaveListen implements Button.OnClickListener{
    @Override

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        savef();
    }

}

public void savef(){
    sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String filename = "aaaaaaa.txt";
    file = new File(sdCard, filename);
    FileOutputStream fileout;
    byte[] thatString = new String("awesome string").getBytes();
    try {
        fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileout.write(thatString);
        fileout.flush();
        fileout.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: so whats the problem? any exception?

Comment: did you give the permission in your manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: The problem is that the file is not saved. It seems like it is working ok but when I exit the program too look at the sdcard the file is not there.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I did use that permission. Thanks

Comment: Refer this site, it has a example for both read and write a file in an external storage http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent all day today trying to figure this out and I finally have an answer. Just thought I would post it here in case anyone else is having a similar issue. I stupidly wrote my permission inside the application block of code instead of below it. Should be like this

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Not like this

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</application>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting an exception, you simply are not seeing it. Instead of `e.printStackTrace();`, which is useless since it doesn't show up in DDMS, use `L.e(TAG, "Error", e);` 
That way you should be able to see the `Exception` and figure out what's wrong